# laravel odd notation in includes like this: @include('flash::message')

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i am using http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/ and am basically 8/10 happy with it. What I saw using it:

they access things via this notation:

`@include('flash::message')`

or:

`@include('core-templates::common.errors')`

why?

and what is an easy way to find the resolution of the reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service Providers are always a good place to start.

Two service providers are registered when using InfyOm.

```
\InfyOm\Generator\InfyOmGeneratorServiceProvider::class,
\InfyOm\CoreTemplates\CoreTemplatesServiceProvider::class,
```

The former, located in

```
/vendor/infyomlabs/core-templates/src/CoreTemplatesServiceProvider.php
```

Has a `boot()` method which registers a view path and namespace.

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../views', 'core-templates');
```

This says when the namespace `core-templates` is used, load from the following directory

```
/vendor/infyomlabs/core-templates/views/
```

The flash one is registered in laracasts/flash which is used by InfyOm to provide flash message functionality.

https://github.com/laracasts/flash/blob/master/src/Laracasts/Flash/FlashServiceProvider.php

Comment: so the reason they use this notation is to easily be able to move folders of views around?